What is Lorentz transformation for a system with two particles?
I have known the Lorentz transformation for one event in two coordinates, connected by Lorentz transformation.
However, if I have two particles (like a Hydrogen atom), in one coordinate it is ($\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2$, t). I have difficulties in understanding what Lorentz transformation it would be for another coordinate.

You must transform two 4-vector $(t, \mathbf{r_1})$ and $(t, \mathbf{r_2})$ separately.. Because of relativity of simultaneity there isnt a uique transformation for two events
